# What's the difference between "Highest Kill Streak" and "Kill Streak Bonus"

Tags: battlefield-3

When I look at the bottom of my stats in Battlefield 3 in the battlelog, under "*All time statistics*" there are "*Highest Kill Streak*" and "*Kill Streak Bonus*" listed with the same number, 20 in my case. I've checked countless other profiles and I didn't find a single one where the numbers were different.

So, do they actually mean the same thing and they screwed it up somehow?

Or is the difference so subtle that people having different numbers are rare?

Answer (score 3):

In the [stats API](http://bf3stats.com/api), there is only one of these stats: `killstreakbonus`. Which would very strongly suggest, that both *"Highest Kill Streak"* and *"Kill Streak Bonus"* are just different display names for same stat.

Comment: I think you're right, but bf3stats.com has no affiliation with EA or DICE.